# module_not_found in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am facing the error below while initializing a React project (`npm init react-app my-app`)

```
PS C:\Users\Abbasi&Ayaz\todo> npm init react-app my-app
'Ayaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Abbasi\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Abbasi&Ayaz\todo
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app "my-app"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abbasi&Ayaz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-01T05_43_26_987Z-debug-0.log"
```

Comment: `npm init react-app my-app 'Ayaz\AppData\Roaming\npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Are you sure `npm` is working in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` command.

Comment: If the problem is about `node_modules`, he shouldn't get `Ayaz\AppData\Roaming\npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command` error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to remove the **&** from the names of any directories in the path to your React applications.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).